# How to run unexpand in all the changed lines in a series of git commits?

Tags: git

I have a series of git commits that, due to different editor defaults, ended up with huge whitespace diffs around every line that I ever touched. This makes git merges significantly harder, and violate the coding standards of the project I want to eventually upstream the changes to.

It's too many to fix manually, so I wanted to use `unexpand`.

However, I cannot just get a list of all the changed files in every commit and run unexpand on them, as some contain embedded tabs and I also cannot make whitespace modifications to lines I do not modify.

**But**, I also cannot run `unexpand` on the new files I add in the commits, as that would disrupt git history (long story).

So, what command/script should I use to run unexpand on all modified lines (but not touch added files) on a series of git commits?

Comment: This is the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413922/convert-spaces-to-tabs-in-lines-i-changed-in-a-commit, isn't it?

Comment: Similar, although that would affect files I added.

Comment: How many commits are we talking about ? up to 3-4 commits ? or more than 10 ?

Comment: _"as that would disrupt git history"_ - that's what rebasing is for.

Comment: "that's what rebasing is for" It would disrupt the git history of the files I am adding, as I want to add them back in the same state they were deleted from the repo in as to simplify git blame. I modify them in later commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by modifying the script from [Convert spaces to tabs in lines I changed in a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413922).

```
#!/bin/bash -e
#
# Rewrite the last commit to remove any trailing whitespace
# in the new version of changed lines.
# Then replace space-based indentation with TAB based indentation
# based on TABS at every eight position
#
[[ -z $TRACE ]] || set -x
trap "rm -f $tmpf" 0
tmpf1=$TMP/$$.1.diff
tmpf2=$TMP/$$.2.diff
git show --binary --diff-filter=a >$tmpf1
perl -p -e 's/^(\+.*?)[ \t]+$/$1/; while(m/^(\+\t*)( {1,7}\t| {8})(.*)/) { $_=$1."\t".$3."\n"; }' <$tmpf1 >$tmpf2
if ! cmp -s $tmpf1 $tmpf2
then
    git apply --binary --index -R --whitespace=nowarn $tmpf1
    git apply --binary --index $tmpf2
    GIT_EDITOR=true git commit --amend
else
    echo "No changes"
fi
```

I modified the git show call to include `--diff-filter=a`, as inspired by the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203). Locally, I modified it to include `--diff-filter=ad`, as that seemed safer to me.

Answer (score 1):

`git diff` has a set of options to [ignore whitespaces under some condition](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---ignore-cr-at-eol).

`git format-patch` can generate a list of patches, taking into account such options, and tuned to be usable by `git am`.

So you can try something along the lines of :

```
git switch -c wip <base_commit>
git format-patch -o ../mypatches --ignore-space-change HEAD..mybranch
git am ../mypatches/*
```

The difficulty will come from applying patches where the spacing does not match the content of your files on disk; if the number of commits to replay is small, this may still be manageable.

Comment: Whût? I thought I recommended before (in the [comments of that other answer of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73133943/6309)) to *not* use `git checkout`!? So, `git switch -c wip <base_commit>`

Comment: :D caught by the git squad !

Comment: This immediately fails when applying patches: https://pastebin.com/ZMhVV4xz